# Not able to stop or pause Music

Tags: android, media-player

I am trying to play music in my app. I am able to play when i click on Play button but not able to stop the music when i click on stop button please help look into this code and point out the issue. i am using pause() of MediaPlayer to pause the music.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Start);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test_cbr);
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.Start:                
            mp.start();
        break;
        case R.id.stop:
            mp.pause();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music Paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

     }
```

I am using a alert message. I am getting this alert message but not able to pause Music.

Comment: dont create new instance of MediaPlayer each time you click button,it must be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your code somethign like this,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 MediaPlayer mp =null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test_cbr);  
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Start);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.Start:   

            mp.start();
        break;
        case R.id.stop:
           if(mp!=null && mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.pause();
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music Paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }

     }
```

The problem could be because you are creating a new instance of media player in your onClick each time and so the previous created one will be playing already but where you are trying to stop the one that is created newly.

So assigning it globally and initiating it newly in start button alone should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are making a new `MediaPlayer` instance every click.

You should have only one instance of a `MediaPlayer`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new Instance every time of media player.Make it global.

Try this changes in your code.

```
case R.id.stop:
     if(mp.isPlaying() && mp!=null)
     { 
       mp.pause();
     }
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music Paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (whatsong) {

    case 1: 
        if(song1.isPlaying()){
            song1.pause();          
        }
```